# FullCalendar: display events on ajax call on modal pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am creating a scheduling system and I want to show each users' schedule using fullCalendar. I need to show the calendar in bootstrap modal and populate the calendar with events via AJAX call.

My problem is when I click the button to show the modal, the events are not showing in the calendar.

[image]

I am using Laravel for my backend and here's the code to retrieve the schedule from the database

```
public function getTeacherScheduleAJAX($id){
    $schedule = DB::table('schedules AS s')
                ->select('s.lesson_name AS title','s.time_start AS start','s.time_end AS end')
                ->where('s.teacher',$id)
                ->get();
    return response()->json([
        'teacher' => $schedule
    ]);
}
```

here's how I do it via AJAX call

```
$('.btn-calendar').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/teacher-schedule/'+$(this).data('teacherid'),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', response.teacher, true);
            $('#scheduleModal').modal('show');              
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
});
```

I have this initialized on page load

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
    header : {
        left:   'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right:  'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView : 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot : false,
    eventOverlap: false
});
```

I am getting responses from my backend, it's just it is not showing in the calendar.

response from query

```
{
"teacher": [
    {
        "title": "English Lesson Schedule",
        "start": "2017-09-08 10:00:00",
        "end": "2017-09-08 12:00:00"
    },
    {
        "title": "English Lesson Schedule",
        "start": "2017-09-13 07:00:00",
        "end": "2017-09-13 09:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can i see the JSON data of `response.teacher`?. I guess you are getting array in response.teacher. i think you will have to use `->first()` instead of `->get()`.

Comment: it won't work since I am retrieving multiple rows from the database so i used `get()`.  `first()` only returns first result of the query.

Comment: then use `$('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvents', response.teacher, true);`  not `renderEvent`

Comment: Let me know if it works then i will post it as a answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render multiple events use

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvents', response.teacher, true);
```

instead of

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', response.teacher, true);
```

`renderEvent` is for single event.